# Accessing a column in an array in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Problem accessing the column "State" from an array in Powershell that is retrieved with a simple get command.

Simple Powershell method and standard column access but does not work for column "State".

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> (Get-HpcNode)

NetBiosName               HealthState     State           Groups
-----------               -----------     -----           ------
EC2AMAZ-33QEW             OK              Online          ComputeNodes
HEAD-NODE                 OK              Online          Compute...

PS C:\Users\Administrator> (Get-HpcNode).HealthState
OK
OK
PS C:\Users\Administrator> (Get-HpcNode).State
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

The column state is defined and has the value "OnLine" which should be displayed.

Comment: are you positive the column name is actually State? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16897769/11734641) question/ answer

Comment: Run `Get-HpcNode | Format-List *` to see the all properties of all objects and check if the property name is correct or if it was changed to provide a more convenient default output format.

Comment: I believe the property is actually called `NodeState`